# Codeigniter form validation unexpected behavior

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I have classic CI controller and index method, in the method I'm trying to validate a very simple form entry.

```
public function index() {

$this->form_validation->set_rules('status', 'Status', 'trim');

if($this->form_validation->run()) {
    echo "true";

    $quote = array(
        'status' => $this->input->post('status'),
        'text' => $this->input->post('text'),
        'author' => $this->input->post('author'),
    );

    $this->quote_model->add($quote);
    set_flash_message('Quote has been added.', 'success');
    redirect('quote');
}
else {
    echo "false";
}

//Some other stuff
```

For some reason every time I submit the form method $this->form_validation->run() returns FALSE and thus code ends up echoing "false". BUT the quote is added to my database as well as 'Quote has been added.' flash message appears, which means the TRUE part of the condition somehow gets executed.

Has anyone ever encountered this issue? I have no idea what could be going on.

Comment: Impossible - you're using just a `trim` and this should run it. I think the "false" comes from somewhere else. - To be sure save the result of `$this->form_validation->run()` into a variable and var_dump it before executing your code.. But you should also check before you run your form validation if there is anything posted (add this: `&& $this->input->post()` to your condition)

Comment: There is literally nothing else than this in my code, apart from loading the views. I tried dumping the result hours ago, and i got 'boolean false'. Adding the condition didn't help. I just cant get it to return true in any way.

Comment: What codigniter version are you using?
AND did you load the library for form_validation?

Comment: Alternative have a look at the full php source code and think what result could be returning false https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Form_validation.php

Comment: I'm using CI v.2.2.0. Yes i did load form_validation in my constructor.

Comment: I think I got, it. It's because of the redirect at the end of TRUE branch of the condition. Yay.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function index() {
        if ($this->input->post()) {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('status', 'Status', 'trim');
            if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
                echo "true";

                $quote = array(
                    'status' => $this->input->post('status'),
                    'text' => $this->input->post('text'),
                    'author' => $this->input->post('author'),
                );

                $this->quote_model->add($quote);
                set_flash_message('Quote has been added.', 'success');
                redirect('quote');
            } else {
                echo "false";
            }
        } else {
            $this->load->view("quote", $data);
        }
    }
```